# How to build multiple architectures from one project, and single from other in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build

My solution consists of Native C++ DLL project, and C# class library. C# class library is a wrapper over native DLL.

Class library is AnyCPU, and native has Win32 and x64 architectures in it.
Basically, I need both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of native DLL built first, and then C# library. It's a strict dependency, because DLL's are embedded into C# library as resources.

1. If it is possible to make from Visual Studio, how to do it?

   In case it is impossible, how to do it using msbuild?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216081/make-a-target-require-both-32-and-64-bit-builds-of-a-dll/46249877#46249877 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

1. Define two different build configurations for your Native DLL, one for the Win32 and the other one for Win64.
2. Suppose that these two builds put their produced DLL into two separate directories, i.e. **build32** and **build64**.
3. Define two different build configurations for your C# library as well. One for 32 bit (config A) and one for 64 bit (Config B). On Config A add the reference to dll in **build32** and in config B add the reference to your native DLL from **build64.**
4. Now let your builder to compiler all the configurations of your native dll first and the C# library next.
5. Every thing will be OK then. !!!