# Make a target require both 32 and 64 bit builds of a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my c++ visual studio solution one project "Proxy" generates a Proxy.dll for Win32 build and Proxy64.dll for x64 build. Now I want to add a Utility project that requires that both Proxy.dll and Proxy64.dll builds. If I set up dependencies I get only one of them depending on current solution platform target. Is there a way to specify that some target depends on multiple builds of another project?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rest of your solution is x64, you can add the following inside the "Project" tags:

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <MSBuild Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' "Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=Win32;PlatFormTarget=Win32" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

If the rest of the solution is Win32, then you would edit the appropriate values inside the MSBuild condition line.